# Question about product topology notation

Tags: general-topology

Instead of using the general form, I will use a simpler one such as $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ (which is $\mathbb{R}^2$ of course).

Now the notation says that the open sets are the union of the sets formed by $A \times B$ where $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval, and $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval. So the actual notation given for this is: $\bigcup_k A_k \times B_k$. Now, say $k = 1$, so $A_1 = (0, 1)$ and $B_1 = (1, 2)$. Then say $k = 2$, and $A_2 = (2, 3)$ and $B_2 = (3, 4)$. Does this mean it is impossible to write an open set $(0,1) \times (3,4)$ in terms of a union of the open sets in the product toplogy? Since $(0,1) \times (3,4) = A_1 \times B_2$, and they have different indices which the notation does not account for.

Comment: Uh, why not define $A_1$ to be $(0,1)$ and $B_1$ to be $(3,4)$?

Comment: @columbus8myhw If we define $A_1$ to be $(0,1)$ and $B_1$ to be $(3,4)$, then we can't write $(0,1) \times (1,2)$ anymore. We would have to switch to a different set $\bigcup_j A_j \times B_j \neq \bigcup_k A_k \times B_k$ (which is a different topology, but the topologies are supposed to be the same for $\mathbb{R^2}$ in this case...which is why I am confused)

Comment: OK, how about keep your definitions and then let $A_3=(0,1)$ and $B_3=(3,4)$? Sure, we have $A_1=A_3$, but that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Oh, thank you. For some reason I thought they were unique, which there is no reason for to believe...

Comment: By the way, geometrically, this means that the topology of $\Bbb R^2$ can be generated by the open rectangles. (Why is the open unit circle open, then? For each point $k$ inside the unit circle, I can give it a rectangle $A_k\times B_k$ containing it and lying inside the circle. Then the circle is just $\bigcup_k A_k\times B_k$. Note that I have uncountably many $k$, but that doesn't matter. Although, I could have restricted myself to rational points, theoretically, to get a countable union.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw Isn't the union just another rectangle?

Comment: How? Every point in the circle is in the union (the point $k$ is in $A_k\times B_k$), and every point in the union is in the circle (because I made sure that $A_k\times B_k$ lies inside the circle). That means they're the same. Think about this geometrically.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I wish there was a visual for this. Geometrically, $A_k \times B_k$ is a closed rectangle that is filled in. Then $\bigcup_k A_k \times B_k$ is just filling in the same rectangle again with the same coordinate points, isn't it?

Comment: No, each $A_k$ is different. For example, if $k$ ranged over the natural numbers, we would have: $\bigcup_kA_k\times B_k=(A_0\times B_0)\cup (A_1\times B_1)\cup(A_2\times B_2)\cup\dotsb$. It's the union of lots of rectangles. In my above example, I had $k$ range over the set of points in the open unit circle.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Then I don't understand the purpose of the rectangle. Why not just range $k$ over the set of points in the open unit circle without the rectangle?

Comment: The point is you want to construct the open sets and only the open sets. Points aren't open. Everything made out of open rectangles is open, though, and everything that's open can be made out of open rectangles.

Comment: There is a way to think about this geometrically. Draw two rectangles that don't touch each other. Is their union a rectangle? No! Now draw a circle and draw a dot inside the circle. Can you draw a tiny rectangle around it that stays inside the circle? Yes! Try it with a different point. You can't do it if the point is on the boundary, but luckily that's not part of the open disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mean what you say, because the index in an expression such as $\;\displaystyle\bigcup_k A_k\times B_k$ is a *dumb* index, i.e. its value doesn't appear in the result, just as in $\;\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^6 k$ there is no $k$: it is only a technical tool to make the effective computation of the sum, $21$.

Comment: Yes, but here there is only one "variable" $k$. If there were another "variable" $j$ included in the summation, you would have to require another restriction on it like $k$ is from $1$ to $6$. If you wanted a sum of $49$, you would range $j$ from $1$ to $7$ which is a different range for $k$. (continued next comment)

Comment: My question felt analagous to wanting $49$ (wanting to get all of $\mathbb{R^2}$ in my case), but you are forced to impose the same restriction on $j$ as you do $k$ (from $1$ to $6$), so you are limited to a sum of $42$ since each $k$ is unique and you are not allowed to repeat e.g. you can't do $6+6+6+6+6+6+6+6+1$ (in my case, I can't get all of $\mathbb{R^2}$).

Comment: Who said $A_k$ and $B_k$ had to be intervals of finite lengths? Who said there had to be a  finite number of such products?

Comment: Also what about the *series*  $\sum_{k\ge 1} 6$?

Comment: I miswrote on my comment. My question was how to write $(0,1) \times (3,4)$ being equivalent to writing $49$ in your first mentioned summation. Since you cannot repeat numbers in that notation, I thought I can't repeat coordinates in the plane in my product notation.

Comment: Oh! I see. Well, don't nee any $\bigcup_k$  really, but you can write as $\bigcup_{k=1}^1 A_k$. Exactly like a term is the sum of $1$ term. I don't see what the problem is, really.

Answer (score 1):

For any topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, Let $\mathscr T_X$ be the topology for $X$, and $\mathscr T_Y$ defined simlarly. The product topology is generated by the collection $\{U\times V:U\in\mathscr T_X,V\in\mathscr T_Y\}$.  By this definition, the indices do no have to match.